# Angular material <mat-selection-list> and <mat-list-option> across template boundaries

Tags: angular, angular-material2

**How to make `<mat-list-option>` -- declared in component `sub` -- "subscribe" to a `<mat-selection-list>` outside component `sub` (say, component `app`)?**

(unfortunately I couldn't manage to make Stackblitz work with my corporate's proxy, so I'll put only the relevant pieces of my examples)

**Example 1** (working, no component `sub`)

(app.component.html)

```html
<div>{{selections | json}}</div>
<mat-selection-list [(ngModel)]="selections">
  <mat-list-option [value]="{x: 1}">x: 1</mat-list-option>
  <mat-list-option [value]="{x: 2}">x: 2</mat-list-option>
  <mat-list-option [value]="{y: 1}">y: 1</mat-list-option>
  <mat-list-option [value]="{y: 2}">y: 2</mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

(app.component.ts)

```js
@Component({
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  selections = [];
}
```

This example works as expected. All 4 options are rendered, and their selections are reflected back in `selections` property (all options' values are javascript objects, and they are correctly inserted to/elided from the `selections` array).

**Example 2** (not working, component `sub` added between `<mat-selection-list>` and `<mat-list-option>`)

(app.component.html)

```html
<div>{{selections | json}}</div>
<mat-selection-list [(ngModel)]="selections">
  <sub></sub>
</mat-selection-list>
```

(sub.component.html)

```html
  <mat-list-option [value]="{x: 1}">x: 1</mat-list-option>
  <mat-list-option [value]="{x: 2}">x: 2</mat-list-option>
  <mat-list-option [value]="{y: 1}">y: 1</mat-list-option>
  <mat-list-option [value]="{y: 2}">y: 2</mat-list-option>
```

(app.component.ts unchanged; sub.component.ts trivial)

This example does render all options as expected. Their selections are not reflected back to the `selections` property (as expected too, because at the point each `<mat-list-option>` get instantiated there is no visible `<mat-selection-list>` for them to subscribe to).

**Example 3** (trying to forward `<mat-selection-list>`, to no avail)

(app.component.ts)

```js
@Component({
  ...
  viewProviders: [{ provide: MatSelectionList, useExisting: MatSelectionList }]
})
export class AppComponent {
  selections = [];
}
```

I expected that this one would work. But I could only get an error:

```
Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! MatSelectionList (...)
```

How to make this work?

**Note**

I'd like to observe that  `ngModel` directive (which works in tandem with `ngForm` and/or `ngModelGroup`) works perfectly across template boundaries just by adding the appropriate `viewProviders` to all intervening components between the one instantiating `ngForm` or `ngModelGroup` (inclusive) and the one instantiating `ngModel` (exclusive).

Their injection pathways are not the same though: `ngModel` gets hold of its parent `ControlContainer` (which subsumes `ngForm` and `ngModelGroup`) via <sup>[[source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/ecffbda664e89c565f5521f33d65ae40618a3f09/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L195)]</sup>:

```js
constructor(@Optional() @Host() parent: ControlContainer, ...) {...}
```

while `<mat-list-option>` does so by <sup>[[source](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/3ec531b71a931a53be0c63c41245e4fc48c4554e/src/material/list/selection-list.ts#L176)]</sup>:

```js
constructor(..., @Inject(forwardRef(() => MatSelectionList)) public selectionList: MatSelectionList) {...}
```

I'm not angular-savvy to know the differences and their implications.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the use case for this. It's probable that you don't need to wrap the `mat-list-option` elements. Your component could include the `mat-selection-list`, or you can simply provide the data and metadata for the options and use `*ngFor` to create the options - no custom component necessary. Or if you prefer, you can create a template-less component that defines the data/metadata which you then use directly in your HTML with original `mat-selection-list` and `mat-list-option` elements. In short, there are probably other ways to achieve what you need.

Comment: @G.Tranter of course there are other ways to achieve this. I myself presented one in my first example (no sub component, `<mat-selection-list>` and `<mat-list-option>` both on the same template). Of course I didn't choose to separate them out of the blue. Architectural considerations are forcing me to do this way. My point is: there should be a way to make these elements communicate. I know it must be possible. After all, `ngModel` directive and companions do this.

Comment: Of course - I am trying to help you - that's why I asked about your use case - to see if other approaches might work better. You have really only described what you are trying and the errors you have encountered - you haven't explained the purpose and goal of what you are trying, which is important in helping you solve the design issue rather than trying to get around an apparent limitation with NgModel and MatSelectionList. But you seem resistant to ideas other than your own.

Comment: Sorry if I sounded arrogant. Yes, you are right in asking for the whole picture because sometimes we don't see other ways to do the same thing. When I posit a question on SO I always try to make things simple, removing all the unnecessary details. The rationale of why I needed to split the two elements in separate components seemed to me much bigger than the problem I was facing. Anyway I felt that what I was trying to accomplish was pretty straighforward and angular-way (afterall it works elsewhere in the angular framework).

Comment: Now, after your answer and a couple more research I think we found a bug in material selection list implementation. I wholeheartedly thank you for the time you spent writing your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in SelectionModel of MatSelectList works fine with the Example 2 approach. It is NgModel that is the problem (this could be a bug or an inherent limitation). You can work around this by listening to the list's selection changes and managing the model directly. For example:

HTML

```
<mat-selection-list [ngModel]="selections" (selectionChange)="handleSelectionChange($event.option)">
  <sub></sub>
</mat-selection-list>
```

TS

```
selections = [];
handleSelectionChange(option: MatSelectionListChange) {
  if (option.selected) {
    this.selections.push(option.value);
  }
  else {
    const index = this.selections.indexOf(option.value);
    this.selections.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: So `<mat-list-option>` indeed gets a reference to `<mat-selection-list>` (as witnessed by `selectionChange` being emitted by `MatListOption._handleClick` [[source](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/4002140363ab364e5abc95dae7013aa73439c112/src/material/list/selection-list.ts#L252)].

Comment: The real culprit is how the `ControlValueAccessor` for `<mat-selection-list>` is implemented. It always accesses an inner `options` property, defined to be a `QueryList<MatListOption>` composed of `@ContentChildren(MatListOption, {descendants: true})` [[source](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/4002140363ab364e5abc95dae7013aa73439c112/src/material/list/selection-list.ts#L330)]. I'll look forward to see if `@ContentChildren` can be made to cross template boundaries. Thanks for pointing the working `selectionChange` event.

Comment: According to [angular documentation](https://v8.angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren), `@ContentChildren "does not retrieve elements or directives that are in other components' templates".